# simple regex /:[a-z]+/ not working as expected in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is a very simple regex code, which works correctly in php and ruby, but not in JS. Plead help me get it working:

```
var r = /:[a-z]+/
var s = '/a/:b/c/:d'
var m = r.exec(s)

// now m is [":b"]
// it should be [":b", ":d"]
// because that's what i get in ruby and php
```

Comment: Why are there 2 downvotes on this question. It's clear, it's concise, it's specific. It's a lot better than what most newcomers post.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester - because there are still many pitchfork and torch wielding folks who don't understand the true nature of the Frankenregex monster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **RegExp.**[`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) with `g` (global) modifier is meant to be used inside a loop for getting all matches.

```
var str = '/a/:b/c/:d'
var re  = /:[a-z]+/g
var matches;

while (matches = re.exec(str)) {
   // In array form, match is now your next match..
}
```

You can also use the **String**.[`match()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method here.

```
var s = '/a/:b/c/:d',
    m = s.match(/:[a-z]+/g);

console.log(m); //=> [ ':b', ':d' ]
```

Comment: Why use `match` ? Why not `exec`?

Comment: Yeah, you should explain the difference a little bit.

Comment: for some reason, i find the edit you made really funny

Answer (score 2):

```
var r = /:[a-z]+/g;  // i put the g tag here because it needs to match all occurrences
var s = '/a/:b/c/:d'; 
var m = s.match(r); 
console.log(m); //  [':b',':d']
```

I used match because it returns all the matches in an array where as with exec you would have to loop through like the other examples.

Comment: Don't just put code in an answer, explain what and why.

Comment: fair enough. I'll explain what I changed and what my results were.